# Use of global declaration inside if statement (Julia Code)

Tags: scope, julia

Why do I have declare variables global when they are in same if elseif else block? What am I missing?

```
function f(N)

for n in 0:N
    if n == 0
        fibonacci_n = 0
        fibonacci_n_1 = fibonacci_n
    elseif n == 1
        fibonacci_n = 1
        fibonacci_n_1 = fibonacci_n
        fibonacci_n_2 = fibonacci_n_1
    else
        global fibonacci_n_1, fibonacci_n_2
        fibonacci_n = fibonacci_n_1 + fibonacci_n_2
        fibonacci_n_1 = fibonacci_n
        fibonacci_n_2 = fibonacci_n_1
    end        
    @printf "%5i %10i\n" n fibonacci_n
end

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Don. Remember to include the tag of the programming language you're working in to attract users with the appropriate knowledge to your question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is not really about global scope and you do not have to declare anything global here. `global` keyword is necessary if you would like a write access to a global variable.

Your `global` keyword introduce new global bindings `fibonacci_n_1` and `fibonacci_n_2`. It does not matter where you put the `global` keyword in the scope. You can even access the last value of `fibonacci_n_1` and `fibonacci_n_2` after the function terminates: try `f(5); println(fibonacci_n_1)` in global scope.

If you remove the `global` declaration in your function, `fibonacci_n_1` and `fibonacci_n_2` will be defined in the local scope of your `for`-loop. Hence, there will not be a global scope access issue. The issue you have, however, will be about the following behavior of variables introduced in loop blocks.

> `for` loops, `while` loops, and Comprehensions have the following behavior: any new variables introduced in their body scopes *are freshly allocated for each loop iteration*, as if the loop body were surrounded by a let block
>
> https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#For-Loops-and-Comprehensions-1

This means that you cannot access a variable's value or binding *in the previous iteration* if you *introduce* that variable inside the `for`-loop. This is *not* similar to the behavior of variables introduced in Python or MATLAB loops.

Instead, you can define such variables outside the for loop but inside the function.

```
function f(N)

fibonacci_n, fibonacci_n_1, fibonacci_n_2 = 0, 0, 0
for n in 0:N
    if n == 0
        fibonacci_n = 0
        fibonacci_n_1 = fibonacci_n
    elseif n == 1
        fibonacci_n = 1
        fibonacci_n_2 = fibonacci_n_1
        fibonacci_n_1 = fibonacci_n
    else
        fibonacci_n = fibonacci_n_1 + fibonacci_n_2
        fibonacci_n_2 = fibonacci_n_1
        fibonacci_n_1 = fibonacci_n
    end        
    @printf "%5i %10i\n" n fibonacci_n
end

end
```

For more relevant discussion about scope of variables in Julia, please see the [Scope of Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/) section of Julia  documentation.